# Facebook API redirect after post is made, not during/before

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Alright, I have this piece of code, straight from the documents which works fine if I leave the setTimeout out of the equation of which redirects a user to where I want them on my service there after.

However if I put the setTimeout in, during the process of the post actually occuring, or right before (not sure which) either way a race condition is created where the post never gets made, and the script redirects accordingly. I am wondering is there another method of handling this where I know the post did/didn't actually make it then redirect. Or how do others handle this situation?

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', obj.data.fb_post, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
    } else {
        //setTimeout(function(){window.location = obj.data.whereTo;}, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you need the timeout for? What happens if you redirect in the success case without setTimeout and no anonymous function, but directly?

Comment: if I put it without the timeout, it just redirects, and no posts on facebook can be found.. only when I comment it out and leave no redirect what so ever will I find the post on FB. It seems overall to me some sort of race condition. Which is even more weird to me as its contained within the if-else based on the FB response .. It shouldn't be triggering either way with/without the timeout until the post is valid on FB

Comment: Do you get a post id in response?

Comment: yes, its rather long and there is a space inbetween making it look like two strings but yes

Comment: but I only see that if the `window.location` as a redirect isn't placed (commmented out)